# How can I make a table with grouped rows like this?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, html-table

I want to make a table that has groups of rows that looks similar to this

[image]

But I can't quite figure it out. I've tried using multiple `<tbody>` elements, adjusting the `colspan` on my `<td>` elements, but neither of those are working for me. If it makes the task any easier, I am using jQuery DataTables.

**edit**: Here's what I have

```
<table id="groupedTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Group</th>                                
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group1</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Group2</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

yes, I know the indentation is wacky, by the editor on here hates me

Comment: Add some of your code so people can improve it.

Comment: @Tavo Ok, it is done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `rowspan`. How does this fiddle work for you?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffozLab8/6/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Group 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple answer. Thank you.